# Vsc not working with Unity in Linux Endeavour

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I work with unity and the VS code autocomplete does not complete many unity objects and more..

my error code is here

[image: error code image]

Comment: First, in Unity go to Edit > Project Settings and assign / reassign VS as your external code editor. If that doesn't work open Package Manager in Unity and reimport VS Tools for Unity. If all else fails uninstall Unity and VS and reinstall Unity, selecting the optional extra of including VS in the installation

Comment: Please don't post error messages as pictures. Instead, paste the text here so it can be found when searching.

Comment: Also, the solution might very well be the suggestion in the error messages. Read them closely.